# Parametrizar la llamada de un procedimiento almacenado

Tags: mysql

Buen día, me gustaría saber si es posible obtener solo algunos valores entre todos los que trae un "Call procedimiento" por ejemplo:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS getProcesos$$
CREATE PROCEDURE getProcesos(IN fk_proyecto INT)
BEGIN
    SELECT id, nombre FROM procesos 
    WHERE estado = 'Activo' and frecuencia in ('Por hora', 'Diaria', 'Semanal', 'Mensual', 'Demanda') and fk_proyecto = id_Proyecto
    ORDER BY FIELD (frecuencia, 'Por hora','Diaria','Semanal','Mensual','Demanda');
END$$
```

De ese procedimiento me gustaría obtener únicamente el id al realizar el call.

Comment: No se entiende bien, si queres obtener solo el `id` en ese procedimiento, entonces a esa consulta `select` solo hay que quitarle `nombre`

Comment: Lo siento, es que no sé muy bien como plantear mi duda. Independientemente de que el select contenga id y nombre, me gustaría saber si es posible obtener solo el id sin alterar el select.

Comment: Creo que tu pregunta es ambigua. Para que usar un Procedure para hacer un select? mejor usar una vista. no vas a poder ver el resultado desde un select, pero si por ejemplo desde un backend, porque lo que devuelve es un resultset que no se puede usar en un select. Tal vez si nos cuentas que queres hacer podemos orientarte mejor.

Comment: Este procedure es parte de uno más grande, el objetivo de este es armar un resultset mediante el id que arroja, consultando en otra vista, pero a su vez el campo nombre es necesario para armar el resultset, por eso considero los 2 datos necesarios. Si bien podría hacer la consulta dentro del procedimiento y ya me gustaría mantenerlo seccionado.

Comment: yo sé muy poco, pero te puedo ayudar a hacer esto: que el procedimiento devuelva variable de salida `out` con el `id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que el procedimiento devuelva variable:

Nota: no sé si es la forma correcta hacer nuevamente la consulta `select`, pero esto es lo que pude hacer.

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS getProcesos$$
CREATE PROCEDURE getProcesos(OUT paramId int, IN id_Proyecto INT)
BEGIN
    SELECT id, nombre FROM procesos 
    WHERE estado = 'Activo' and frecuencia in ('Por hora', 'Diaria', 'Semanal', 'Mensual', 'Demanda') and fk_proyecto = id_Proyecto
    ORDER BY FIELD (frecuencia, 'Por hora','Diaria','Semanal','Mensual','Demanda');
    -- acá asigno a la variable de salida paramId
    SELECT id INTO paramId FROM procesos 
    WHERE estado = 'Activo' and frecuencia in ('Por hora', 'Diaria', 'Semanal', 'Mensual', 'Demanda') and fk_proyecto = id_Proyecto;
END$$
```

Para ejecutarlo desde consola mysql hago así:

```
set @fk_proyecto_in =6;
call getProcesos(@id_procesos_out, @fk_proyecto_in);
select @id_procesos_out as idProcesos;
```

Comment: Retorna el select vacío, probé la consulta y es correcta, sin embargo cuando se ejecuta desde el procedimiento no funciona.

Comment: estoy viendo que me comí el `;` al final del último `select`, ya lo edito,  arreglalo y decime si funciona

Comment: No, lo arreglé antes. ¿Podría ser por la versión de MySQL que uso?

Comment: Cambié el orden de las consultas y ahora tengo el siguiente error: `#1172 - Resultado compuesto de mas que una línea`

Honestamente no lo entiendo

Comment: la verdad no se, pero tengo la versión 5.5.24. Cuando llamas al procedimiento respetas el orden de los parámetros? `call getProcesos(@id_procesos_out, @fk_proyecto_in);`

Comment: te voy a pasar mi procedimiento con el que hice las pruebas con mi base de datos para que veas que yo uso el delimitador de otra forma, quizá sea eso, probá usando el delimitador de esta forma

Comment: DELIMITER $$
create procedure p_ejemplo(OUT param1 INT, in id int)
begin
  select idventa,cantidad,idproducto from detalleventas where iddetalle =id;
  select cantidad into param1 from detalleventas where iddetalle =id;
end;
$$
DELIMITER ;

Comment: fijate que cambia al final. Vos haces `END$$` y yo hago `end;
$$
DELIMITER ;`

Comment: pero no uso el `DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS`, si no que lo elimino manualmente si existe

Comment: Ya funcionó, solo se trata de que el límite de registros no es de solo 1 y por eso no puede recorrerse con un select normal, muchas gracias por tu ayuda.